# Powershell scripting - in middle of writing, how to undo?

Tags: scripting, powershell-3.0

I'm new to powershell and as such finding my fingers are hitting wrong keys which produces the `>>` symbol. How to I 'undo' that to continue with the initial script?

E.g:

```
$i=0; get-childitem $dirname | foreach-object {...rest of script and I miss closing a bracket or something then get... >> and can't remove that and continue writing script.
```

I'm sure it's an easy key combination that I haven't found yet, but better than closing app and re-opening.

Answer (score 0):

That symbol is a line continuation. Just keep typing as though you didn't hit Enter and it will treat everything as the full line you intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "undo" and restart writing your script you can press:

```
Ctrl + C
```